# Route Middleware in Slim 4 doesn't stop invoking the callable in the route

Tags: php, routes, middleware, slim-4

I'm strugling with authorization middleware in Slim4. Here's my code:

```
$app = AppFactory::create();
$app->add(new Authentication());

$app->group('/providers', function(RouteCollectorProxy $group){
    $group->get('/', 'Project\Controller\ProviderController:get');
})->add(new SuperuserAuthorization());
```

Authentication middleware checks the user and works fine.

The method **get** in ProviderController is

```
public function get(Request $request, Response $response): Response{
    $payload = [];
    foreach(Provider::all() as $provider){
        $payload[] = [
            'id' => $provider->id,
            'name' => $provider->name,
        ];
    }
    $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($payload));
    return $response;
}
```

The SuperuserAuthorization looks like this

```
class SuperuserAuthorization{
    public function __invoke(Request $request, RequestHandler $handler): Response{
        $response = $handler->handle($request);
        $authorization = explode(" ", $request->getHeader('Authorization')[0]);
        $user = User::getUserByApiKey($authorization[1]);
        if(! Role::isSuperuser($user)){
            return $response->withStatus(403);//Forbidden
        }
        return $response;
    }
}
```

The thing is that even though the user is not a superuser, the application continues executing. As a result I get json with all the providers and http code 403 :/

Shouldn't route middleware stop the request from getting into the app and just return 403 right away?

I know that I can create new empty response with status 403, so the data won't come out, but the point is that the request should never get beyond this middleware, am I right or did I just misunderstand something here…

Any help will be appreciated :)

------------- SOLUTION ----------------

Thanks to @Nima I solved it. The updated version of middleware is:

```
class SuperuserAuthorization{
    public function __invoke(Request $request, RequestHandler $handler): Response{
        $authorization = explode(" ", $request->getHeader('Authorization')[0]);
        $user = User::getUserByApiKey($authorization[1]);
        if(! Role::isSuperuser($user)){
            $response = new Response();
            return $response->withStatus(403);//Forbidden
        }
        return $handler->handle($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Shouldn't route middleware stop the request from getting into the app and just return 403 right away?

Slim 4 uses [PSR-15](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-15/) compatible middlewares. There is good [example](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-15/meta/#reusable-middleware-examples) of how to implement an authorization middleware in PSR-15 meta document. You need to avoid calling `$handler->handle($request)` if you don't want the request to be processed any further.

As you can see in the example, if the request is not authorized, a response different from the return value of `$handler->handle($request)` is returned. This means your point saying:

> I know that I can create new empty response with status 403, so the data won't come out, but the point is that the request should never get beyond this middleware

is somehow correct, but *you* should prevent the request from going further by returning appropriate response *before* invoking the handler, or throwing an exception and let the error handler handle it.

Here is a simple middleware that randomly authorizes some of requests and throws an exception for others:

```
$app->group('/protected', function($group){
    $group->get('/', function($request, $response){
        $response->getBody()->write('Some protected response...');
        return $response;
    });
})->add(function($request, $handler){
    // randomly authorize/reject requests
    if(rand() % 2) {
        // Instead of throwing an exception, you can return an appropriate response
        throw new \Slim\Exception\HttpForbiddenException($request);
    }
    $response = $handler->handle($request);
    $response->getBody()->write('(this request was authorized by the middleware)');
    return $response;
});
```

To see different responses, please visit `/protected/` path a few times (remember the middleware acts randomly)

Comment: Thank you @Nima. I wish I asked the question earlier. I updated my middleware now and it works as intended. Cheers :)

Comment: Glad to help :)